# How can I derive the 4th kinematic equation from #1 and #3?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

That is to say, how can I take:
\begin{align} 
 v&= v_i + at \\
 \Delta x &= v_i \cdot t + \frac{at^2}{2}
\end{align}
and derive $v^2 = v_i^2 + 2a \Delta x$?

I've spent hours trying to finagle this derivation and am still stuck. My thought process is to solve the first equation for t, and plug the result into the second equation, but I get lost somewhere in between.

Answer (score 1):

$V = Vi + at$ so $t=\dfrac{V - Vi}{a}$ then
\begin{align}
ΔX &= Vit + 1/2at^2\\
&=Vi\left(\dfrac{V - Vi}{a}\right) + 1/2a\left(\dfrac{V - Vi}{a}\right)^2\\
&=\left(\dfrac{VVi - Vi^2}{a}\right) + \left(\dfrac{(V - V_i)^2}{2a}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{V^2 - Vi^2}{2a}
\end{align}